# T-SQL How to select rows without duplicate values from one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 2 columns `ID, ID_PROJ_CSR`

The content of that table is:

```
ID     ID_PROJ_CSR
------------------
747    222   <
785    102
786    222   <
787    223
788    224
```

I want to select the ID, but if any value from ID_PROJ_CSR is a duplicate, I need to select any ID of the rows that contains that duplicate value (in that example, select ID **747** OR **786**

I try:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table tab 
WHERE tab.id_proj_csr = (SELECT TOP 1 id_proj_csr
                         FROM my_table mt
                         WHERE mt.id_proj_csr = tab.id_proj_csr)
```

Comment: Maybe something like `select ID from my_table where ID_PROJ_CSR IN (select ID_PROJ_CSR from my_table group by ID_PROJ_CSR HAVING count(ID) > 1)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to GROUP BY:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) as [ID], ID_PROJ_CSR
FROM my_table
GROUP BY ID_PROJ_CSR
```

Comment: +1 Nice and simple. Think its also worth mentioning that you got around the duplicate IDs, by using MAX.

Comment: What if the table have more columns to retrieve with? i have a similar issue, and the given response works if i just want id and id_proj_csr, but when i need more columns to be retrieves it starts asking to add them to the group by and start retrieving incorrect records.

Comment: @brayancastrop - you can use MAX(any_column) or MIN(any_column) to select an individual value for that column

Answer (score 1):

Here's the case of omitting anything that has a duplicate value, so you'll only get rows that don't have duplicates:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
GROUP BY ID_PROJ_CSR
HAVING count(ID_PROJ_CSR) = 1;
```