# Suppressing a repeated column value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

For example if we have the values:

```
username             Category
-------------------- ----------
Brian                cs
Tom                  cs
Joe                  cs
Allen                cs
Bill                 ts
Steven               ts
Fred                 ts
Ted                  ts
```

I Need an Output  as

```
username             Category
-------------------- ----------
Brian                cs
Tom                  
Joe                  
Allen                
Bill                 ts
Steven               
Fred                 
Ted
```

I have Tried

1)  [T-SQL How to select rows without duplicate values from one column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682956/t-sql-how-to-select-rows-without-duplicate-values-from-one-column)

2) http://www.rajapet.com/2010/04/suppressing-repeated-column-value-in.html

3) [How to select records without duplicate on just one field in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239169/how-to-select-records-without-duplicate-on-just-one-field-in-sql)

Nothing Work well ( What i Expected)

Is there any other way ?

Comment: The canonical way to do this is to do all visual formatting in your report writer, not in SQL. I think you'll find that most report writers will have something like "suppress repeating values".

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) for this:

```
select username, 
       case when rn = 1 then cat else '' end as category
from (
   select username, 
          category as cat, 
          row_number() over (partition by category order by username) as rn
   from the_table
) t
order by cat, username;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/423ed/4

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative way, using a subquery. Note that both answers will give the category value to the first username alphabetically i.e. Allen will get cs, and Bill ts.

```
select a.username,b.category from
foo a
left join
(select category,min(username) as username from foo group by category) b
on b.username = a.username
order by a.category,a.username
```

[EDIT] If you want to assign to the first instance in your table (i.e. return what you put in your question), you can do something like this:

```
    with foobar as 
        (select username,category, row_number() over() as rownum from foo )

   select a.username,coalesce(b.category,'') as category from
    foobar a
    left join
    (select category,min(rownum) as rownum from foobar group by category) b
    on b.rownum = a.rownum
    order by a.rownum,a.username
```

Comment: You might want a COALESCE or something similar to make NULLs into empty.